# update viewmodel in knockout and update the UI

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

below is my javascript that loads the model and i binded it to a dropdown and a table to show data. which works and shows the data.

```
var _observableViewModel = null;     
$(document).ready(function () {
                var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))';
                _observableViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel);

                ko.applyBindings(_observableViewModel);
            });
```

once a user selects the an item from the dropdownlist i am calling a ajax function that returns jsonresult and want to update the viewmodel and update the table as well. i tried something below but no effect.
i am using mvc.
thanks for the help!

```
 function GetData() {

            $.getJSON("/Home/Test", function (data) {

                ko.mapping.updateModel(data);


            })
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve can be done with ko.mapping. I mean you should call mapping again it might work.

Comment: what is your object ko.viewModel? what is your ko.viewModel.updateModel attempting to do?

Comment: @beauXjames i already have my _observableViewModel binded to my table and i am trying to update it again so it will reflect the new data on my table

Comment: I 'understand' that...point is, if you don't show me what your 'updateModel' function is doing, I can't be of any help...best way to get assistance is to generate a fiddle if you're having trouble putting it into words.

Comment: @adt i did try ko.mapping.updateModel(data); which dint work either

Comment: 'updateModel' doesn't exist...are you expecting it to?

Comment: i am sorry i put in the wrong code, i have updated it with what @adt mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are already using ko.mapping you really should use the mapping overload specifying a target :

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, {}, _observableViewModel)
```

It will update the observable as before, as well as calling the observable valueWillMutate / valueHasMutated methods to update the UI.

Comment: @darius...zsri is needing more than a one-liner for a solution...probe for more information first before trying to score a green check

Comment: yeah i would have but i still don't have enough rep to comment on the thread above

Comment: cool, its updating my UI now, my model has two objects in it object 1 and object 2  , object 1 contains dropdown data and object 2 contains table data, and i want it to update only object 2 data, how can i do it ? thanksss alll

Comment: are the objects in the model observable as well ?

Comment: ya under one Model object i have these 2 objects and all are observable

Comment: you can try two ways. first is calling the mapping with the ignore option: `ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, { ignore: ["object1"] }, _observableViewModel)`

Comment: the other way might be using a custom update mapping option, where you assign only object 2 data on update.

Comment: @zsri...make a fiddle with your scenario otherwise it's just going to be a comment trail nobody wants to follow

Comment: i got it working, when i am updating the object 2 i just send that object alone and change my code to ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonData, {}, _observableViewModel.Object2) and its working, thanks!!!!    i am not familiar with fiddle but will try it thanks again